# XPath to get another attribute by id attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am using XPath to pull data off of a web page.

I have a link that I want to get the href value of. I can reference it through its unique id: `id('unique-id')`, but that gives me the string between the `<a>` tags.

How do I get the value of the `href` attribute?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try this XPath: `//a[@id = 'unique-id']/@href`. This XPath will select `href` attribute of `a` element with attribute `id` = `unique-id`